# How to renew a variable in another function within a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class with a few functions in it, in my `change_date` function I need to reassign the the `self.date` variable in the `__init__`. However, initially, I need `self.date = yesterday()`, how can I reassign this from the other function, and then continue with the processes of `__init__` with the new date?

```
class PVData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = yesterday()
        self.data = load_data(self.date)

        #time, temp, sun
        self.time = []
        self.temperature = []
        self.sunlight = []
        self.powerlist = [] ####LIST OF ALL POWER TUPLES FOR DAY
        for minute in self.data:
            self.time.append(minute[0])
            self.temperature.append(minute[1])
            self.sunlight.append(minute[2])
            self.powerlist.append(minute[3])
        ##power

        self.placelist = []
        for i in ARRAYS:
            self.placelist.append(i)

        ##Combine lists to dictionary with loop
        self.dictionary = {}
        self.dictionary = dict(zip(self.placelist, self.powerlist)) 




def change_date(self, date):
        if self.date != date:
            self.date = date
            self.__init__()           
            #self.refresh()
        else:
            self.date = date
```

Comment: You don't need to call `self.__init__()`. When you create a `PVData` class it will call `__init__()` for you automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you'd want to refactor most of your `__init__` logic into a different function, e.g. `_initialize` that uses `self.date` to set everything else up...

```
class PVData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.date = yesterday()
        self._initialize()

    def change_date(self, date):
        if self.date != self.date:
            self.date = date
            self._initialize()

    def _initialize(self):
        self.data = load_data(self.date)

        #time, temp, sun
        self.time = []
        self.temperature = []
        self.sunlight = []
        self.powerlist = [] ####LIST OF ALL POWER TUPLES FOR DAY
        for minute in self.data:
            self.time.append(minute[0])
            self.temperature.append(minute[1])
            self.sunlight.append(minute[2])
            self.powerlist.append(minute[3])
        ##power

        self.placelist = []
        for i in ARRAYS:
            self.placelist.append(i)

        ##Combine lists to dictionary with loop
        self.dictionary = {}
        self.dictionary = dict(zip(self.placelist, self.powerlist))
```

Comment: Instead of having an initilize function would I be able to utilize the `else` part of the if statement and then call `change_date` in the init?